# Post-Christmas - Christmas Movie Rebuses

Tags: rebus, movies, seasonal

You wait all holidays for a Christmas movie rebus and three come along at once!

[image]

Can you deduce the films from the images?

If you enjoyed these, there are some trickier ones here:

> [The Revenge of the Post-Christmas - Christmas Movie Rebuses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47333/the-revenge-of-the-post-christmas-christmas-movie-rebuses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: if I may ask, are the movies also christmas related?

Comment: @MarioGarcia They all have a Christmas setting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first one seems to be:

> [Die Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Hard)

The second one is

> [Home Alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Alone)

And the last one is

> [Kiss Kiss Bang Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_Kiss_Bang_Bang)

Comment: I think that is Die Hard 2. Due to the 2 arms..

Comment: @Sid I don't think so :-) https://www.joe.ie/movies-tv/10-reasons-why-die-hard-is-the-greatest-christmas-film-of-all-time/479242

Comment: Correct! Think the last one is more than 'could be' though.. !

Answer (score 7):

**ANSWER:**
I think

> 1 is Die Hard . (as pointed out by OP and @IAmInPLS)
>  2 is Home Alone
>  3 is Kiss Kiss Bang Bang (As pointed out by Mike Limburg)

Comment: What do you think of the last picture, should "Kiss kiss bang bang" fit?

Comment: it is worth a try

Comment: @MikeLimburg Possible.. I haven't seen that movie. Is it christmassy? I was thinking more on the lines of something to do with women (XX chromosome)

Comment: Think you may have over thought the first one, but your other answers are correct :)

Comment: @Sid Well, kinda. I did not see the movie either, but the photos on the IMDB site say enough: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373469/