# The Revenge of the Post-Christmas - Christmas Movie Rebuses

Tags: rebus, movies, seasonal

Rather enjoyed my first outing as a poser in [Post-Christmas - Christmas Movie Rebuses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47327/post-christmas-christmas-movie-rebuses) so I have made some more. Hopefully these should be a little trickier!

[image: xmas movie rebuses 2]

Deduce the three movies from the images.

N.B. All movies are Christmas themed or set at Christmas.

**HINT**

As image 2 has yet to be deduced, I have updated it in the spoiler tag below. Hopefully this should make the answer more apparent:

> [image: xmas movie rebuses 2b]

Comment: Wow, already a new one? You posted the previous one about two hours ago. Just for your visibility, I suggest that you leave some time between posts :-).

Comment: The last one was my first question, and I enjoyed it so much I figured I'd have another pop! Thanks for the advice though, will bear it in mind!

Comment: Is there some significance to the four rectangles below the blank squares in the first picture?  Having trouble placing what all of that is, exactly.

Comment: @Tipler, Yes, the whole image is a rather specific reference that is essential to figuring out that particular movie. I realise, with hindsight, this reference may not be all that well-known outside Britain.

Comment: So, what about the second one? Is it widely known? I'm thinking about ybir npghnyyl but I don't see how it fits

Comment: @IAmInPLS I have added a hint and yes, it is widely known. Also, the clue shouldn't require any specific knowledge.

Comment: That heart sure is awe-full.

Comment: the second one is still unsolved!? hrmmmmm

Comment: @curtisk All are solved, see [Neil W's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47346/17890). My comment meant he got 2 out of 3 personally as the solution to the 1st rebus is accredited to DooplissForce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally got one :)

The third one:

> Ghost bust ERs Two = **Ghostbusters II**

Oh no... is the second one:

> The most famous Christmas movie of all, **It's a Wonderful Life**? Awe = wonder, heart is a symbol of life, or a life in many video games, since awe fills the heart, it's a wonder-full life!

And the first one thanks to DooplissForce is:

> **A Christmas Carol** the image depicts the set for the UK show Countdown, and the figure is in the role once filled by Carol Vorderman, hence, with the Santa hat is a Christmas Carol.

Comment: Fantastic! Was rather proud of that one, glad someone got there :)

Comment: Hah, nice job.  I didn't consider a statuette or bust, when looking at it.

Comment: Hey, good job for the second one (+1). I think this should be it :-)!

Comment: Winner! As you got two of the three, I think I can award you the tick.. bounty is coming as soon as I can award.. good work :)

Comment: Cheers @Arth!!!

Answer (score 6):

Is the first one maybe:

> A Christmas Carol? The board with the letters on it is from the British game show Countdown, and the letters in the rebus unscramble to **Christmas**. The hostess who (up until 2008) [put the letters up on the board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vab3n.jpg), and thus the figure to the right of the board in the rebus, is **Carol** Vorderman. Thus, A Christmas Carol.

Comment: Good work! That is correct, in hindsight I could have put more emphasis on the stick figure, but you got it :)

Comment: @Arth Thanks! I'm glad my love for British game shows has finally come in handy on this site ;)

Comment: And you didn't assume it was Rachel Riley either ... http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/03/02/263C3F6E00000578-0-image-a-1_1425337593840.jpg

Comment: @Lembik As much as I would love to see it, there's unfortunately no movie called A Christmas Rachel, haha

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**

First one:

> [A Christmas Carol](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1067106/) as Doopliss Force figured out

Second one:

> [Hearts of Christmas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1847615/)

Third one:

> As Neil W found out: [Ghostbusters II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters_II)

Comment: +1 for trying.. but keep guessing! They are all movies.

Comment: I should maybe point out that none of these are correct.. sorry.

Comment: Thought so as my answer was a wild guess... I'm still struggling with the last picture. Do I see Queen Elizabeth II twice? Tough puzzle this is :)

Comment: You do (with some important addition).. these clues, particularly the second two, have a much more cryptic feel to them!

Comment: Added a possible answer for number 1 to your answer, Mike.

Comment: Still none I'm afraid.. although the second and third answers you have for the first are feasible, they are on the wrong(ish) track.

Comment: @Arth Gahhh, I want to know it already! I will keep looking for (better) answers...

Comment: Another possible for number 1, then:  [Spoiler Link](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTExMzM4NDIxNjJeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDcwODUyMDMx._V1_UY268_CR9,0,182,268_AL_.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Second could be

> [A Mighty Heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mighty_Heart_(film)) (Awe may be an expression of seeing something powerful) or [Heartaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartaches_(film)) (Awe can be an expression for sadness/ache) or [The Heart's Cry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heart%27s_Cry)(Awe can be an expression of pain)  or [Heartbreaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbreaker_(2010_film))(Awe is the expression of broken heart.. If we take it as if its breaking the heart). 
>
>  
> I think all of these fit well.

Comment: You might want to explain the rebus as well. How do 'AWE' and the paint fit?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Done. Not sure if any of those is intended though.

Comment: Thanks, but none of them are correct I'm afraid.. The paint is a very specific symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Guess for #2:

> [Big Bad Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bad_Love)

Because:

> Heart (**love**) is filled with awe.  Filled with awe = awful = **bad**.  And "AWE" is written in **big** letters.  But I don't know if this movie is related to Christmas in any way at all.

Comment: No, this is not related to Christmas at all.

Comment: Was afraid of that..  Oh well.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't right.. I wouldn't say awe translates as bad, but it does translate!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's my guess for number 2, just going on the idea of what is going on with the rebus:

> How The Grinch Stole Christmas.... his heart was too small and was filled with awe at how Christmas continued despite his plot...making his heart grow

Comment: Thanks, but that is incorrect.. the rebus points to the title of the movie, there is no indication of plot (other than the separate condition that it be Christmas related).